# Why does Xcode successfully build & copy my application, but won't launch it?

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode

Developing an iPhone application on Xcode 4.5.2. Device: iPhone 4.

I was preparing my application for sending it to someone through testflight. I created a distribution profile and certificate for this. I did it following this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/11917884/555690

Anyway, recently, Xcode is unable to launch my project. When I press Run, it will successfully build and copy the files to the device, but when attempting to launch it, it will send an error:

> Error launching remote program: No such file or directory
>   (/Users/Me/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MyGame-xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/MyGame.app/MyGame).

I'm not sure why is this happening.

A very similar question is this: [Xcode successfully builds my target, but does not run the product](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8244953/xcode-successfully-builds-my-target-but-does-not-run-the-product), however, it seems to be more oriented to OSX instead of iOS, and the solutions there haven't helped me either. Also, I do get an error (he doesn't get an error).

If I run the app in the device (without Xcode), it works fine.

Comment: Did you try cleaning the project and removing the derived data folder?

Comment: I also have similar issue, dunno I was never able to debug on device. But my application was approved by Apple and now is live. I am also waiting for this question to be answered..

Comment: @DrummerB: Yes, the problem persists.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, this happens a lot in the new Xcode.

One recipe that should work is:

- disconnect the device from computer
- delete app from device
- reset the device
- quit the xcode (not just by closing the project, quit the program)
- in Finder go to ~/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData
  (Library folder is hidden: you can open Finder->Go->Go to Folder...)
- delete all subfolders there
- empty the trash
- reconnect the device
- open the project
- now you should be able to run the app on the device again

Comment: You're welcome! I have to use this 'recipe' almost every day :/ glad it helps.