# Xcode freezes when it reaches a breakpoint, while testing on a device

Tags: ios, xcode, debugging

I set a breakpoint in Xcode and run my app on a device. Xcode stops at the breakpoint and the console opens, but I just see a spinning wheel instead of a list of all the variables and Xcode sort of freezes. Nothing happens when I push the Stop button. It unfreezes only if I unplug the device. This just started happening last week.

Other times it will list the variables, but when I click the arrow next to "self" for example, the same "freeze" happens.

**This does NOT happen while testing in the simulator.**

Any ideas?

Comment: I've seen this too. Sometimes XCode eventually remembers it's trying to debug (sometimes several minutes), other times it doesn't.  I put it down to the fact it's Xcode and thus one expects this kind of behaviour..

Comment: :D Do you know about any solution to this?

Comment: If I did there's be an answer slightly further down the page :-)

Comment: It's not necesserily related, but i would try this recipe: http://stackoverflow.com/a/14447705/653513 It helped me with several different symptomps.

Comment: @NikolayDyankov: sorry, i wanted to upvote and downvoted by mistake. Can you make a small difference to your question so i can change my vote?

Comment: Upgrade to latest XCode?

Comment: @NikolayDyankov, is your code running on several threads? I have noticed that this can throw the debugger off at some breakpoints? One other thought,have you tried to change the Optimization level to none to see if that stops happening?

Comment: @Spectravideo328 Yes, my code is running on several threads. I haven't tried turning off Optimization... will try it if I find where to do it :)

Comment: Select the project in the navigator -> Build settings -> Apple LLVM compiler Code generation section -> expand optimization level -> change debug setting to none.

Answer (score 2):

This worked for me:

Close Xcode.  Open Finder, hit <kbd>⌘</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>G</kbd> to open "Go to Folder".

Type ~/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData

Delete all folders in this directory and empty trash.  Reopen Xcode and try again.

This is thanks to rokjarc ([Why does Xcode successfully build & copy my application, but won't launch it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14447267/why-does-xcode-successfully-build-copy-my-application-but-wont-launch-it/14447705#14447705))

Answer (score 2):

Just restart your development machine. Worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem as you i just updated my version of xcode this fixed it for me if that doesn't work reinstall the current version you have. You can do that here but you need to be an apple developer member to do so https://daw.apple.com/cgi-bin/WebObjects/DSAuthWeb.woa/wa/login?appIdKey=d4f7d769c2abecc664d0dadfed6a67f943442b5e9c87524d4587a95773750cea&path=%2F%2Fdownloads%2Findex.action

Answer (score 0):

**This is not a solution**

I tried the methods explained on this as well as a couple of other answers and forums but none of them worked for me in my situation.

I have edited the launch attribute to *Wait for executable to be launched* instead of *Automatically*. It is to test when user opens a app from a push notification when it is not started at all. The debugger would stop and never allow for any step through or **po** commands.

I just used logging after spending about 2 hours trying to fix the issue. If you are facing similar issues in a very narrow scenario then **print()** could save you time.

Answer (score 0):

I have tried below options one or the other works

- Removing derived data or doing Clean build folder in xcode
- Removing and readding break points
- Restarting xcode or development machine
- Closing all the memory suck applications

Answer (score -1):

Happened to me once.
Try to delete the Breakpoints.xcbkptlist file. (deletes all placed breakpoints)
and then put back your breakpoint and try again.

Good luck.